# IOS Local Push Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode5, uilocalnotification

I am making a connection to a JSON file using AFNETWORKING. I want to send the user a Local Push Notification when an object in the json changed. For example:

```
{ "result": 
    [
        {"status":"TRUE"}
    ]
}
```

changed to

```
{ "result": 
    [
        {"status":"FALSE"}
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to check if the object has changed when the application is in the background? Or do i need to use Push Notification from a server (APN).

Comment: First of all, local notifications are different from (remote) push notifications. On iOS7 there is a new functionality to do background fetching but as far as I know you cannot notify the user if the content has changed, so it won't be noticeable till next time the app is opened.

Answer (score 1):

No You cant check if the object has changed when the application is in background. You can do this by using  Push Notification. Here is a tutorial for push notification

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of iOS7, you can use background fetch as [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a). But, using this will consume battery and also it is not certain that your app will get the chance to invoke the background fetch.

considering this, Push notification is the best option to go with.